# IBM MQ Java - transactions

Tags: java, ibm-mq

On a MQQueueManager there doesn't seem to be a concept of a named transaction.

We only have a commit() / backout() method.

If I want 2 concurrent transactions then I must create 2 MQQueueManager connections.

This doesn't seem right. You wouldn't for example create 2 JDBC connections for 2 separate transactions.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Are you running your Java application on a WebSphere Application Server, or is it a standalone application?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the session controls the transaction. So you can use the same connection object, but you need to create two sessions from it.